# javascript for update clock isn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script from the internet to update clock automatically, this is the script:

```
function timer(){
             var now     = new Date,
                 hours   = now.getHours(),
                 ampm    = hours<12 ? ' AM' : ' PM',
                 minutes = now.getMinutes(),
                 seconds = now.getSeconds(),
                 t_str   = [hours-12, 
                            (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes),
                            (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)]
                             .join(':') + ampm;
             document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = t_str;
             setTimeout(timer,1000);
            }
```

I put that script within `<head>` tag. This is my header:

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/rhinoslider-1.05.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rhinoslider-1.05.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function timer(){
             var now     = new Date,
                 hours   = now.getHours(),
                 ampm    = hours<12 ? ' AM' : ' PM',
                 minutes = now.getMinutes(),
                 seconds = now.getSeconds(),
                 t_str   = [hours-12, 
                            (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes),
                            (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)]
                             .join(':') + ampm;
             document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = t_str;
             setTimeout(timer,1000);
            }
        </script>
</head>
```

UPDATE: i'm sorry to all people that answer my querstion, i'm forget to onload that script :(

Why is the script not working?

Comment: You need to trigger your function.

Comment: Any errors? Where is your id="clock" tag? Also replace `now = new Date` with `now = new Date()`

Comment: How does it "not work"?  What does it do?  What does it not do?  Do you see any errors?  Have you tried to debug it yourself?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre `new Date;` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: The `()` are optional when using `new` if you are not passing any params.  `now = new Date` is valid :)

Comment: i had putted in <div id='clock'></div>

Answer (score 3):

You defined a function, but you never called it.
Therefore, it never runs.

You need to make sure to call it after `document.getElementById('clock')` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Can you trigger the `timer()` on body onload

```
 <body onload="timer()">
```

Comment: you can but it's nasty :P

Comment: @Emissary, Thanks. But How you said that ? any explanation?

Comment: don't worry - I'm referring to inline-js in general.  `window.onload` would be a nicer example :)

Comment: @Emissary, Haaaaa!. Every one have their own options and preference to use. :)

Comment: oh god i'm forget to call with onload :(

Answer (score 0):

The script is putting the text for your clock in an element with an `id` of "clock". You need that element on the page, and you need to call your function once the page is rendered.

For example:

```
<body onload="timer()">
    <div id="clock"></div>
</body>
```